# Java's equivalent to php.net?

Tags: java

Where can I find useful resources to Java.

- all Java functions and syntax explaining (like php.net)
- mac widgets with all functions gathered (like php function reference)

Would be great if you had links to very good resources/tutorials to share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaDoc in CHM format for easily searching

http://www.allimant.org/javadoc/index.php

[Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/) is an invaluable reference as already said

I think you should just get Eclipse or your favorite IDE and add the Javadoc to the build path of the jar

EDIT:

**Window\Preferences\Java\Installed JREs**

Select the JRE

Press Edit

Javadoc URL: point to the URL

Shift + F2 should take you to the appropriate function definition
, and i must say it is very productive =]

Answer (score 4):

you should start with the [Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the auto-completion feature of your editor.

In Eclipse: Write "[name of your object].", Press [CRTL]+[SPACE] and then read the javadoc of the suggested functions/methods.

Answer (score 0):

[Java API Documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/) explains all classes and methods.

[Java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/) has very good examples for Java

Comment: -1, Like exampledepot.com: it's a huge list of many (not all!) bad practices and unreferenced copy-and-pasted code snippets from books.

Comment: Java API documentation + Java2s means what PHP.net is. PHP.net has an official documentation + user examples which also has bad practices and sometime mistakes but it is great resource. Please read the question again, he is not asking for best practices, he is not asking for referenced codes. Of course you can ask for these in your **own** question. I would try to answer :)